# Why does ctrl + D not raise EOFError and shortens my input string on the THIRD time I press it

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```py
while(True):
    try:
        text = input("What do you want?\n")
        print(text)
    except EOFError:
        print("EOFError")
```

I run my script  in the terminal (both on Linux and macOS) and it prompts me for input.
If I don't type anything and just hit ctrl + D EOFError is raised as expected and as per the documentation: (Raised when the input() function hits an end-of-file condition (EOF) without reading any data.)

If I START typing something and press ctrl + D, nothing happens. I press it a second time - nothing happens. Only on the THIRD time this happens:
on the same line of my input, immediately after my input, it prints the text WITHOUT the last character.
So if I typed 123 it prints 12.

I have two questions: 1. Why do I get this behaviour, when I have started to write something?
2. How to force my program to do the following:
After starting to type and hit ctrl + D once it just prints the whole string OR sends EOFError

Tested on both linux and macOS.

Comment: This is not under your control.  It is operating system behavior.  From stdin, Ctrl-D is only defined as EOF when it is at the start of a line.  Two Ctrl-Ds is interpreted as an  "end-of-line".

Comment: Sorry, don't have an answer to your question, but I'm curious how you're running Python on iOS?

Comment: @TimRoberts more like shell/terminal dependent.

Comment: @Pragmatic_Lee oops, macOS :)

Comment: I probably look at `input()` implementation here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dcdc90d384723920e8dea0ee04eae8c219333634/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2082